# How can I include a module from another file from the same project?

Tags: rust

By following [this guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/guide.html#crates-and-modules) I created a Cargo project.

**`src/main.rs`**

```
fn main() {
    hello::print_hello();
}

mod hello {
    pub fn print_hello() {
        println!("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

which I run using

```
cargo build && cargo run
```

and it compiles without errors. Now I'm trying to split the main module in two but cannot figure out how to include a module from another file.

My project tree looks like this

```
├── src
    ├── hello.rs
    └── main.rs
```

and the content of the files:

**`src/main.rs`**

```
use hello;

fn main() {
    hello::print_hello();
}
```

**`src/hello.rs`**

```
mod hello {
    pub fn print_hello() {
        println!("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

When I compile it with `cargo build` I get

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `hello`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use hello;
  |     ^^^^^ no `hello` external crate
```

I tried to follow the compiler's suggestions and modified `main.rs` to:

```
#![feature(globs)]

extern crate hello;

use hello::*;

fn main() {
    hello::print_hello();
}
```

But this still doesn't help much, now I get this:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `hello`
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | extern crate hello;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

Is there a trivial example of how to include one module from the current project into the project's main file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rust basic imports (includes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224947/rust-basic-imports-includes)

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596920/split-a-module-across-several-files

Answer (score 465, accepted):

You don't need the `mod hello` in your `hello.rs` file. Code in any file but the crate root (`main.rs` for executables, `lib.rs` for libraries) is automatically namespaced in a module.

To include the code from `hello.rs` in your `main.rs`, use `mod hello;`. It gets expanded to the code that is in `hello.rs` (exactly as you had before). Your file structure continues the same, and your code needs to be slightly changed:

**`main.rs`**:

```
mod hello;

fn main() {
    hello::print_hello();
}
```

**`hello.rs`**:

```
pub fn print_hello() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: Late Question wouldn't it also work if I specify it with use hello instead of mod hello?!

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt No, they are different things. `use` is just a namespace thing, while `mod` pulls in the file.
You would use `use`, for example, to be able to call the `print_hello` function without having to prefix with the namespace

Answer (score 100):

If you wish to have nested modules...

## Rust 2018

It's [no longer *required*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#no-more-modrs) to have the file `mod.rs` (although it is still supported). The idiomatic alternative is to name the file the name of the module:

```
$ tree src
src
├── main.rs
├── my
│   ├── inaccessible.rs
│   └── nested.rs
└── my.rs
```

**`main.rs`**

```
mod my;

fn main() {
    my::function();
}
```

**`my.rs`**

```
pub mod nested; // if you need to include other modules

pub fn function() {
    println!("called `my::function()`");
}
```

## Rust 2015

You need to put a `mod.rs` file inside your folder of the same name as your module. [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.41.1/rust-by-example/mod/split.html) explains it better.

```
$ tree src
src
├── main.rs
└── my
    ├── inaccessible.rs
    ├── mod.rs
    └── nested.rs
```

**`main.rs`**

```
mod my;

fn main() {
    my::function();
}
```

**`mod.rs`**

```
pub mod nested; // if you need to include other modules

pub fn function() {
    println!("called `my::function()`");
}
```

Comment: Suppose I wanted to use something from `inaccessible.rs` in `nested.rs`... how would I do that?

Comment: To access a sibling .rs file from a file other than main.rs, use the path attribute.  So, at the top of nested.rs, add the following:   `#[path = "inaccessible.rs"]` and on the next line: `mod inaccessible;`

Comment: @Gandhi See [The path attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html)

Comment: @HemanGandhi add `mod inaccessible;` to `my/mod.rs` to make it submodule of `my`, then access sibling module from `nested.rs` by relative path `super::inaccessible::function()`. you dont need `path` attribute here.

Comment: I'm not sure the 2018 way of naming the file after the directory is more idiomatic. I for one prefer the old approach for a clean directory tree, and plenty of crates also follow it.

Comment: Am I weird for thinking that the 2015 example makes more sense?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid both `mod.rs` and also the extra top-level file, `my.rs`?

Answer (score 55):

I really like [Gardener's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-to-include-a-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project#comment100874493_49476448). I've been using the suggestion for my module declarations.

```
./src
├── main.rs
├── other_utils
│   └── other_thing.rs
└── utils
    └── thing.rs
```

#### File *main.rs*

```
#[path = "utils/thing.rs"] mod thing;
#[path = "other_utils/other_thing.rs"] mod other_thing;

fn main() {
  thing::foo();
  other_thing::bar();
}
```

#### File *utils/thing.rs*

```
pub fn foo() {
  println!("foo");
}
```

#### File *other_utils/other_thing.rs*

```
#[path = "../utils/thing.rs"] mod thing;

pub fn bar() {
  println!("bar");
  thing::foo();
}
```

Comment: Had to use this 'trick' to reexport `fn` with same name as the file it was in. `#[path = "./add_offer.rs"] mod _add_offer;
pub use self::_add_offer::add_offer;`

Comment: As a Rust newbie, it's a bit disturbing that such a simple concept  (importing other bits of code) requires so much research. Plus the #[path..] syntax is ugly

Comment: This is misleading, the `#[path = ...]` attribute should not be used except in obscure cases, and certainly not by newbies. Each time you do `mod thing`, it *creates a new module*, even if `#[path = ...]` makes them point to the same file. Meaning in this sample, there are two separate `thing` modules declared: `crate::thing` and `crate::other_thing::thing`. Its likely not an issue here since it only includes a function, but if you define types, it can lead to confusion when the compiler reports "expected mod1::A, found mod2::A".

Comment: Please use the standard mechanisms. If you really want this file structure without intermediate `mod.rs` files, you can declare them in `main.rs` like `mod other_utils { pub mod other_thing; }` and `mod utils { pub mod thing; }`. Then you can access them like `crate::other_utils::other_thing` and `crate::utils::thing`.

Answer (score 11):

In a non *main.rs* (or *lib.rs*) file if you want to include from a file in the same directory then the code below works. The key is to use the word `super::` for the include. (This is how I rewrote the [answer of rodo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-can-i-include-a-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project/59692102#59692102) without using `path`.)

Directory tree:

```
src
├── main.rs
├── my.rs
└── my
    ├── a.rs
    └── b.rs
```

To include *a.rs* in *b.rs*:

#### File *src/my/a.rs*

```
pub fn function() {
    println!("src/my/a.rs/function()");
}
```

#### File *src/my/b.rs*

```
use super::b::function;

fn f2() {
    function();
}
```

#### File *src/my.rs*

```
mod a;
mod b;
```

#### File *src/main.rs*

```
mod my;
```

Answer (score 7):

**As of 2022**

```
├── src
├── main.rs
├── scripts
│   └── func.rs
└── scripts.rs
```

If I want to call the functions from the `func.rs` file (which are inside the `scripts` folder), I created a so-called "linking" file in the root directory the same as the folder's name (it's not necessary to have the linking file name and the folder name the same).

Content of file *scripts/func.rs*:

```
pub fn sayHello(){
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
```

In the *scripts.rs* file I have:

`pub(crate) mod func;`

Then in my `main.rs` file I have called the `sayHello()` function as below:

```
mod scripts;
fn main() {
    scripts::func::sayHello();
}
```

Comment: Re *"As of 2022"*: Can you [state](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71943939/edit) the version(s) of stuff (compilers, conventions, documents/specifications, etc.)? Perhaps also which system (incl. versions) this was tested on. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 6):

There's sort of two cases to this question, and the answers I've seen so far only cover one case: when you have a `main.rs`, and `a.rs`, and a `b.rs`, all in the same directory, but you want to use functions from `a.rs` or `b.rs` in `main.rs`, but I haven't seen anyone cover the opposite case, so I'll do that here.

Given `main.rs`, `a.rs`, and `b.rs` all in the same directory, and **you want to use functions from B in A, or A in B**:

### In `main.rs`

```rust
mod a;
mod b;

use crate::a::*;
use crate::b::*;

// To call a function from a.rs, do:
a::my_function_from_a();
```

### In `a.rs`

```rust
use crate::b;

// To call a function from b.rs, do:
super::b::my_function_from_b();
```

The [`super`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/super.html) keyword in `a.rs` is where the magic happens. Annoyingly, the behavior is different than the Ruby version of `super`.

If you don't use the super keyword you'll get the dreaded: `[E0433] use of undeclared crate or module`.

Comment: Why do I need "mod b;" in `main.rs` if I don't use it in `main.rs`?

Comment: @Velkan That's in case you call a function from the `b.rs` file.

Comment: Yes, I call a function from the `b.rs` file in `a.rs`, not in `main.rs`. Why do I need to care about `main.rs`? It doesn't use anything from `b.rs`.