# Include Module Rust

Tags: rust

My question is pretty similar to [How to include module from another file from the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-to-include-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project), in that I am trying to import a `mod` into my **main.rs** and use it, except my `mod` has a private and public function.

**sys.rs**

```
mod sys {
    fn read_num_lines(file: File, num_lines: i32) -> bool {
        //do bar with foo
    }
    pub fn get_cpu_stats() {
        //call read_num_lines
        //doo foo
    }
}
```

**main.rs**

```
mod sys;
fn main() {
    sys::get_cpu_stats();
}
```

I get the following build error:

```
unresolved name sys::get_cpu_stats
```

Since this is my first Rust project, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but am unsure as to what that something is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **sys.rs** to:

```
fn read_num_lines(file: File, num_lines: i32) -> bool {
    //do bar with foo
}
pub fn get_cpu_stats() {
    //call read_num_lines
    //doo foo
}
```

since the file **sys.rs** is already a module scope. I could have also written `sys::sys::get_cpu_stats();`

Thanks to June in IRC!