# Why can't I import module from different file in same directory?

Tags: module, rust

My directory structure:

```
src
    main.rs
    image.rs
    decoders.rs
```

When I try to import my decoders module in image.rs I get this:

```
error[E0583]: File not found for module `decoders`
```

decoders.rs:

```
pub mod Decoders {}
```

image.rs:

```
mod decoders

use decoders::Decoders

pub mod Image {}
```

Note: I am using a module that wraps the entire file on purpose that's I can put attributes on entire files. This is why it's not a duplicate of [How to include module from another file from the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-to-include-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project)

The weird thing is, is that this syntax works perfectly fine when I try to import Image in main.rs:

```
mod image;

use image::Image;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _on purpose that's I can put attributes on entire files_?

Answer (score 8):

What's happening is that when you try to import `decoders::Decoders` in `image.rs`, you need to go through the next level up, because using this:

```rust
mod decoders

use decoders::Decoders
```

Means that `decoders` will now be "owned" or under `image`, which means that the compiler will search in the `image` subdirectory for `decoders.rs`. So, to fix this, you can either change your file structure to this:

```
src/
    main.rs
    image.rs        ** or image/mod.rs
    image/
        decoder.rs
```

Or, use this in `main.rs`:

```rust
mod decoders;
mod image;
```

and this in `image.rs`:

```rust
use super::decoders::Decoders;
//Or alternatively
use crate::decoders::Decoders;
```

Also, to fix your nested-mod problem, do the following in `decoders.rs`:

```
//Your code, no `mod Decoders`
```

and the following where you have your `mod decoders` statement:

```
#[your_attribs]
mod decoders;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! This part saved my day:
> Means that decoders will now be "owned" or under image, which is impossible since only lib.rs, mod.rs or main.rs files can have modules in other files

Answer (score -1):

The rust compiler resolves modules differently depending on where they're defined.

When you use the `mod` keyword to declare an external module from the crate entry point (typically `main.rs` or `lib.rs`) or from a module root (`mod.rs`), the compiler will search for files adjacent to the declaring file. This is why it works properly when using `mod image.rs` in your `main.rs` file.

In other cases, the compiler will search for files in the folder with the same name as the declaring file. In your case, this means that your `mod decoders;` line in `image.rs` results in the compiler searching for the module in the `image` subfolder - specifically checking `image/decoders.rs` and `image/decoders/mod.rs`.

To fix this, you can either move `decoders.rs` to `image/decoders.rs` if you want to keep `decoders` as a submodule of `image`, or alternatively place `mod decoders;` in `main.rs` and leave the file where it is.