# How to use modules from another directory?

Tags: module, rust

I have a Rust project with the structure:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── mod.rs
│   │   ├── router_get.rs
│   │   └── router_post.rs
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── server.rs
```

I need to use the routes module in `server.rs`, but when I am trying to compile it, it gives me an error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::routes`
  --> src/server.rs:10:5
   |
10 | use super::routes;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ no `routes` in the root
```

When I try use `routes` in `main.rs` with `mod routes`, everything is ok. But I need to use it in `server.rs`.

routes/mod.rs

```
pub mod router_get;
pub mod router_post;
```

Comment: Please search before you post a question; many questions about using modules has been asked and answered on here. To apply the answer to the other question: you need `mod routes;` in main.rs, *as well as* `use super::routes;` in server.rs.

Comment: Also see [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module) and [Why can't I import module from different file in same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55868434/3650362)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `main.rs` you've to load the module first.

```
mod routes;

fn main() {
}
```

In your `server.rs` just use

```
use crate::routes;
```