# Split main.rs into files that refer each other

Tags: module, rust, rust-crates

I have the following structure:

```
|-- Cargo.toml
|-- src
|   |-- file1.rs
|   |-- file2.rs
|   `-- main.rs
```

src/file1.rs

```
pub fn function1() {}
```

src/file2.rs

```
// ERROR (1): error[E0583]: file not found for module `file1`
// mod file1;

use crate::file1;
pub fn function2() {
    file1::function1();
}
```

src/main.rs

```
// ERROR (2): no `file1` in the root
// use crate::file1;
mod file1;
mod file2;

fn main() {
    file1::function1();
    file2::function2();
}
```

Basically, I have a different way to import `function1`, depending on the fact that I am in the crate root or in an arbitrary Rust file (please see `ERROR (1)` and `ERROR (2)`).
I am a bit lost on how Rust manages arbirary files: they behave differently from the root crate, where a simple `mod` keyword does the trick.
So, the mentioned answer for which this is a duplicate only partially only answers how to refer a file from the crate root, not *why* referring the same file from another one should be different (`use crate::<filename>`).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-to-include-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PeterHall. Well, that partially answers my question, as it does not include non-crate roots modules referring each other (see src/file2.rs).

Comment: Place the `mod` statements in the parent module. This is how to tell Rust that the sub-modules exist at all.

Comment: All paths are addressable as fully-qualified paths from the root. You can think of it as writing relative paths inside files on a file system, where the `crate` keyword is like `/`, start at the root.

Comment: You never actually _need_ to use `use` statements. They are for convenience to not have to type the full paths everywhere. And they are relative to where you are in the module hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks again @PeterHall. That is pretty clearer. My last doubt is: why am I using different ways of referring for `main.rs` and `file2.rs`? It must be related with the fact that one of them is the crate root but I cant't see a substantial difference.

Comment: @PeterHall I am adding `pub mod f1` in `file1` and `pub mod f2` in `file2` but now I do not know how to refer them in the crate root. `use` is not accepted, neither `mod f1` does.

Comment: You could write `use crate::file1;` inside main.rs too. But it would mean there would be two copies of `file1` in scope. The difference is that the modules are already in scope in main because main is the immediate parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196439/discussion-between-fcracker79-and-peter-hall).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include module from another file from the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-to-include-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project)