# Multiple files in a (binary) project

Tags: module, rust

I'm trying to grok the appropriate way to split up my binary project into multiple files. In the Rust book, [7.1 Packages and Crates](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates.html) starts off by including an example of creating a `bin` project with cargo, but the rest of the examples are `lib`. I don't really care about the hierarchy of my code since I'm not exposing it in a library. Other, older questions ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-to-include-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project)) mention that you generally need `<module_name>/mod.rs`; while this isn't strictly required, it does seem appropriate for larger library projects.

I have three files:

**src/main.rs:**

```rust
mod A;
mod B;

fn main() {
    let a = A::A { a: 123 };
    let b = B::B { b: 3.14 };

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

**src/A.rs:**

```rust
use crate::B;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct A {
    pub a : u32
}

impl From<B::B> for A {
    fn from(b : B::B) -> A {
        A { a: b.b as u32 }
    }
}
```

**src/B.rs:**

```rust
use crate::A;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct B {
    pub b : f32
}

impl From<A::A> for B {
    fn from(a : A::A) -> B {
        B { b: a.a as f32 }
    }
}
```

This works as expected (snake case warnings removed for brevity):

```
$ cargo run
A { a: 123 }
B { b: 3.14 }
```

However, this seems like a bit more song-and-dance than should be necessary: qualifying references with their module name for every reference  seems excessive. I would have assumed that I could do something like `mod A::A` or `use A::*` to 'import' types, functions, etc.

Is this the expected, idiomatic way to split code up?

### Edit:

Per discussion, I updated my source to use `use a::*`. New code is:

**main.rs:**

```rust
mod a;
mod b;
use a::*; // !
use b::*; // !

fn main() {
    let a = A { a: 123 };
    let b = B { b: 3.14 };

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

**a.rs:**

```rust
use crate::b::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct A {
    pub a : u32
}

impl From<B> for A {
    fn from(b : B) -> A {
        A { a: b.b as u32 }
    }
}
```

**b.rs:**

```rust
use crate::a::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct B {
    pub b : f32
}

impl From<A> for B {
    fn from(a : A) -> B {
        B { b: a.a as f32 }
    }
}
```

Including both `mod a;` and `use a::*;` (changed to follow `snake_case` convention, but importantly to prevent name conflicts with the previously uppercase `A` module from conflicting with the still-uppercase `A` struct) now lets components be referenced without qualification.

Comment: *is this the expected, idiomatic way to split code up?* — **yes**.

Comment: *or `use A::*` to 'import' types* — yes, you can. That's the exact syntax.

Comment: You may wish to re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html), which covers these topics.

Comment: If I specify `use A::*;` and remove the qualifications (eg, `let a = A { a: 123 };`), I get the error _error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `A` in this scope_

Comment: Is this in `B.rs`? Then it's `use crate::A::*;`. `use A::*;` would be what you'd type in `main.rs`.

Comment: In main.rs, I say `use A::*` and `use B::*`; in a.rs and b.rs, I `use crate::B::*` and `use crate::A::*`, respectively. Qualifications are then removed. I get unresolved imports on A and B and the above failure to find the structs.

Comment: I did not suggest removing the `mod` statements. Again, I highly recommend reviewing *TRPL*.