# What is the proper way to organize your code/tests in Rust?

Tags: rust, integration-testing, directory-structure

In Chapter 11, section 3 (11.3) of the Rust book, it discusses the procedure for introducing integration tests into your project. In short, create a sibling directory to 'src' named 'tests' and locate your test code in a file in the 'tests' directory. The file contents from the example in the book are shown below:

```
 use adder;

#[test]
fn it_adds_two() {
    assert_eq!(4, adder::add_two(2));
}
```

The 'src/lib.rs' file has its code declared within a module:

```
mod adder {
  ...
}
```

This didn't work for me. I had to remove the module declaration in 'lib.rs' and add this ahead of the 'use adder;' declaration in my integration tests file:

```
extern crate adder;
```

So, I'm confused. Has something changed in the language and the docs haven't caught up yet? Is the code contained in a library ('src/lib.rs') not allowed to be organized into modules? If someone could point me to a comprehensive summary of code organization in Rust, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The book doesn't tell you to put `mod adder {...}` inside `lib.rs`. The book's example is compiling a crate named `adder`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a module from another file from the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-to-include-a-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `src/lib.rs` into:

```rust
pub mod adder {
...
}
```

or if you have a module in a file called `adder.rs`, then just put `pub mod adder;`

The important thing to note is that each file is a module and the `pub` keyword is needed to expose the module from the crate.

Then in your integration tests files (under `/tests/`), do:

```rust
use <cratename>::adder::<whatever you want to import or *>;

fn main() {
...
}
```