# How to break a large Rust impl block into files?

Tags: rust

Here is what I have in `foo.rs`:

```
pub struct Foo {
  // a few attributes
}

impl Foo {
  // 20+ public functions 
}
// 100+ tests
```

The file is too long (2000+ lines of code). How can I break it into files without changing the structure of the code: I want to still have one struct `Foo` with many functions and many unit tests.

Comment: You can have multiple `impl`s on multiple files. But we cannot really help without more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the tests make up a large portion of the file. If you have followed the usual pattern of having tests in a submodule (`mod tests`) then the
simplest way to break up this file is to move the `tests` module to a separate file.

You can either:

- create a directory `foo` containing `mod.rs` with the non-test code and `tests.rs` with the contents of the `tests` sub-module, or
- keep `foo.rs` with the non-test code and create a directory `foo` only containing the `tests.rs` file.

```
// Keep this in foo.rs or move to foo/mod.rs
pub struct Foo {
  // a few attributes
}

impl Foo {
  // 20+ public functions 
}

// Replace this module with `mod tests;`
mod tests {
    // move the contents to a new file `foo/tests.rs`
    // 100+ tests
}
```

Comment: You didn't forget to put `use` in `foo.rs`?

Comment: Having `mod tests;` in `foo.rs` and the `foo/tests.rs` file is equivalent to having `mod tests {...}` in `foo.rs`. No need to add `use`.

Answer (score 3):

Rust allows you to have `impl` blocks in separate files. So you can have, for example:

In `file1.rs`:

```
pub struct Foo {
    // a few attributes
}
```

In `file2.rs`:

```
impl Foo {
    // some methods
}
```

In `file3.rs`:

```
impl Abc for Foo {
    // other methods
}
```

In `file4.rs`:

```
impl Xyz for Foo {
    // other methods
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that if you have private fields in your struct `Foo` (the default, i.e. you don't add `pub` or any other visibility modifiers to your fields) , you can still access them in other files, but there is a restriction: they can only be accessed by the current module and its descendants.

Comment: How should I make these files visible to the compiler? I should somehow mention them in `foo.rs`?

Comment: You will add them to the module system, as usual - by creating the module with `mod fileN` and using with `use path::to::fileN`.

Comment: You don't need `use`.

Comment: @yegor256 Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49476448/15602349).