# Impossible to compile multiple files in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am a beginner in Rust and am looking to compile a project that contains several files, here is the structure :

```bash
├── src
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── strutils
│       └── get_wide_str.rs
```

Here are the contents of `main.rs` :

```rust
use windows::core::*;
mod strutils;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    return Ok(())
}
```

And the contents of `get_wide_str.rs`:

```rust
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
use winapi::um::winnt::LPCWSTR;

pub fn get_wide_str(src: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    let wide_chars: Vec<u16> = OsStr::new(src)
        .encode_wide()
        .chain(std::iter::once(0))
        .collect();

    return wide_chars
}

pub fn get_wide_ptr(src: Vec<u16>) -> LPCWSTR {
    src.as_ptr()
}
```

When I do `cargo build` I get the following error:

```bash
error[E0583]: file not found for module `strutils`
```

How can I "split" my code cleanly in Rust?

So I tried to create a mod.rs but it makes the code ugly and redundant, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49476448/5397009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `get_wide_str.rs` is nested in the `strutils` module, it is inaccessible to `main.rs`. Therefore, you need to make the `get_wide_str` module accessible to other modules that use `strutils`—using `pub mod`.

Create a `mod.rs` file in the `strutils` directory (`strutils/mod.rs`) which contains the following:

```
pub mod get_wide_str;
```

**Alternatively,** in `main.rs`, declare the module `strutils` and include the submodule `get_wide_str` :

```
mod strutils {
    pub mod get_wide_str;
}
```