# Using a module from another

Tags: module, rust

There is something that I don't get about Rust modules.

## With a single file used in `main.rs`

With a `main` and another file, I get how to use them. This is quite straightforward.

*main.rs*

```rust
mod other;

fn main() {
    let whatever = other::Whatever {
        foo: 32,
    };
    println!("Whatever is {}", whatever.foo);
}
```

*other.rs*

```rust
pub struct Whatever {
    pub foo: u32,
}
```

This is fine.

## What about using it somewhere else than in `main.rs`?

What I don't get is when it comes to using that other module in another module.

Here is what sounded good to me but did not work.

*main.rs*

```rust
pub mod other;
pub mod alter;

fn main() {
    let whatever = other::Whatever {
        foo: 32,
    };
    alter::say(whatever);
}
```

*other.rs*

```rust
pub struct Whatever {
    pub foo: u32,
}
```

*alter.rs*

```rust
mod other;

pub fn say(whatever: other::Whatever) {
    println!("Whatever is {}", whatever.foo);
}
```

Compilation fails:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `other`
 --> src/alter.rs:1:5
  |
1 | mod other;
  |     ^^^^^
  |
```

How can I use `other` from `alter`?

I already saw [How to use one module from another module in a Rust cargo project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071513/how-to-use-one-module-from-another-module-in-a-rust-cargo-project) but from what I understand, it refers to a module and its submodule.

Here, `other` is not a submodule of `alter` (you may consider `other` as an application-wide shared configuration for instance).

Comment: This somehow looks familiar: [How to use functions from one file among multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260772/how-to-use-functions-from-one-file-among-multiple-files/54261498#54261498); [Rust basic imports (includes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224947/rust-basic-imports-includes).

Comment: Indeed, but I get for src/alter.rs:1:5 when for `use other`: "no `other` external crate". I don't get what I miss...

Comment: Prepend `crate::` to `other`: `use crate::other;`. That's a recent change in edition 2018, I'll update one of the linked answers.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's all good, thanks a lot Andrey!