# Required to use module name twice to reference a struct in the module

Tags: rust

Main function is as follow:

```
mod stats;

fn main() {
    let raw_data = [10, 10, 20, 1, 2, 3, 5];
    let mut v: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mean = 0;
    let median = 0;
    let mode = 0;
    for i in raw_data.iter() {
        v.push(*i);
    }
    let stat = stats::stats::Stats::new(v);
}
```

And module stats as follow:

```
pub mod stats {
    pub struct Stats {
        data: Vec<u32>,
    }
    impl Stats {
        pub fn new(data: Vec<u32>) -> Stats {
            Stats { data }
        }
        pub fn find_mean(&self) -> f64 {
            let mut sum = 0;
            for i in &self.data {
                sum += i;
            }
            return (sum / self.data.iter().count() as u32) as f64;
        }
        pub fn find_mode(&self) -> u32 {}
        pub fn find_median(&self) -> f64 {}
    }
}
```

Why do I have to use `stats::stats` to reference struct `Stats`.

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your `stats.rs` file you create another module `stats` which means, that you have to use `stats::stats`, because every file creates its own module.

To solve your issue, just remove `pub mod stats` in your `stats.rs` file.

For further information see:

- [The book Chapter 7](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-02-modules-and-use-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html)
- [How to I do a basic import/include of a function from one module to another in Rust 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224947/how-to-i-do-a-basic-import-include-of-a-function-from-one-module-to-another-in-r)
- [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module)
- [How to use functions from one file among multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260772/how-to-use-functions-from-one-file-among-multiple-files)
- [What are the valid path roots in the use keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289071/what-are-the-valid-path-roots-in-the-use-keyword)