# How do I import functions from subfolders in Rust

Tags: function, rust, module, directory, subdirectory

I have the main main.rs in the src folder.
The main.rs contains the following content.

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    hallo();
}
```

The main.rs in the src/lib folder does not currently have any content.

How can I now use the function "hello" from the test.rs in the main.rs in the src folder?
The test.rs contains the following content.

```
fn hallo(){
    println!("hallo");
}
```

My folder structure looks like this.

````
|   Cargo.lock
|   Cargo.toml
|           
+---src
|   |   main.rs
|   |   
|   \---lib
|           main.rs
|           test.rs
```
````

Comment: This question has been asked many times on this site. See [How do I do a basic import/include of a function from one module to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224947/how-do-i-do-a-basic-import-include-of-a-function-from-one-module-to-another-in-r)

Comment: I suggest reading this article, it is the best explanation of the module system out there imo: [Rust modules vs files](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/rust-modules-vs-files)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This gets into the Rust module system. I'll try my best to explain it, but the Book does a much better job, so if you're confused, go ahead and check it out [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html). Basically, each file in Rust (besides main.rs or lib.rs) corresponds to one module in a crate (main.rs and lib.rs are the crate's root). Everything in that file is exposed under that module. To create a module, you add this line to its parent module (or to lib.rs or main.rs, which makes it a submodule under the crate):

```rust
mod somemod;
```

Then, you have two options:

- Add a file called `somemod.rs` in the same folder as the file where you put that `mod somemod;` declaration. Your file structure would look like this:

```
|
+---main.rs
+---somemod.rs
```

- Add a folder called `somemod` in the same folder as the file with the `mod somemod;` declaration. This would be used if you wanted `somemod` to have child modules; you'd use the same two options to create child modules as you did to create the top-level one. Your file structure looks like this:

```
|
+---main.rs
+---somemod
    |
    +---mod.rs
```

Then, after that line (and before, if you really wanted), you'd be able to use the `somemod` *namespace* to refer to any public member of the `somemod` module:

```rust
mod somemod;

// later on ...
somemod::foo();
```

You could also use the `use` keyword to bring a member of `somemod` into the current namespace:

```rust
mod somemod;
use somemod::foo;

// later on ...
foo();
```

So, in your case, your code would look like this:

main.rs:

```rust
mod test;
use test::hallo;

#[allow(dead_code)]
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    hallo();
}
```

test.rs:

```rust
pub fn hallo() {
    println!("hallo");
}
```

Note that in order to be able to reference `hallo` from outside the module, we had to add the `pub` keyword in from of `fn hallo`.

Comment: Please check for duplicates before writing up an answer. If your answer is distinct in some way, you can post an answer on the duplicate. You help a lot more people that way :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am learning `rust-lang`. 
This is what I understood about module imports.
Let your project structure be like,

```
---- src /
      |
      ---- main.rs
---- Cargo.lock
---- Cargo.toml
```

Now you created a folder called `parent` along with `main.rs` like,

```
---- src /
      |
      ---- main.rs
      ---- parent /
             |
             ---- child /
                    |
                    ---- my_file.rs
---- Cargo.lock
---- Cargo.toml
```

To import a function `my_function` from `my_file.rs`,

Step 1: Create a file called `lib.rs` along with `main.rs`
Step 2: Add empty `mod.rs` in `parent` and `child` folders.
Step 3: In `lib.rs` add `pub mod parent`
Step 4: In `mod.rs` of `parent`, add `pub mod child`
Step 5: In `mod.rs` of `child`, add `pub mod my_file`
Step 6: In `main.rs` add `mod parent`
Step 7: Finally, use it by `parent::child::my_file::my_function()`

Final project structure will be like,

```
---- src /
      |
      ---- main.rs                   // mod parent
      ---- lib.rs                    // pub mod parent
      ---- parent /
             |
             ---- mod.rs             // pub mod child
             ---- child /
                    |
                    ---- mod.rs      // pub mod my_file
                    ---- my_file.rs
---- Cargo.lock
---- Cargo.toml
```

Hopes this will help.

Comment: lib.rs file isn't required any more, if a mod.rs file exist in the parent folder.

Comment: @lli how are you referencing to modules in subfolders without lib.rs can you describe?